# Варианты связи между классами

Tags: java, ооп

Есть например два класса Document и User. У Document есть поле creator (из числа существующих пользователей). Как стоит задать такое поле? по id класса User или напрямую подставлять User?

```
private Integer userId;
OR
private User user;
```

В идеале услышать минусы/плюсы вариантов кратко. Спасибо

Comment: А зачем нужно поле `creator`? Что вы с ним делаете в программе?

Comment: Например ищем документы, созданные определенным пользователем (кстати поиск по id или по имени тоже может влиять на выбор структуры?). Хотя именно для такого варианта может  быть стоит в User тоже создать поле для связи со списком созданных документов. Но например мы имеем еще какие-то ограничения кроме пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не могу найти у себя в голове ни одного аргумента в пользу варианта:

```
private Integer userId;
```

Причем неважно: one-to-many, many-to-one и т.д.

Во всех известных мне реализациях DAO/ORM используется всегда связь типа:

```
private User user;
```

Ну разве что в терминах ORM это может быть раскрыто приблизительно так (пример по [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/)):

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = userId, index=true, foreign = true)
private User user;
```

Откуда примерно понятно, что в реале связь естественно через `userId`, но конечный DAO объект уже будет `private User user`

Answer (score 0):

Вариант `private User user`, как по мне, более правильный с точки зрения проектирования БД. Задаете связь `oneToMany`, `oneToOne` и в таблице БД `Document` получите айди `user`. `Document` со всеми `user` можно получить одним запросом выборки с документов. Так же само можно получить все документы по нужному пользователю.

Далее еще важен вопрос сколько может быть `user` на `document`. Если один, то вариант с айдишкой, в принципе, тоже можно использовать, хотя и не совсем правильно.

Если же `user` на `document` будет больше одного, тогда однозначно лучше использовать указанные выше связи, либо вариант `manyToMany`

Comment: Мне кажется что именно ссылку на класс в поле привязать более прозрачно, но через id связи - больше структуру БД напоминает. Предположим изначально что у нас это не в БД хранится, а просто в памяти на время работы проги.